# How to make a no-gui virtual machine on a server?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-server

I've got this Ubuntu server I'm running, and it's really handy to take the load off of my laptop, but I'd like to know how to set up a virtual machine on it that I can ssh into. Obviously, this removes things like VirtualBox from the equation, since I'm currently in a command line.

I've googled this question, but to no avail. Everything just tells me to run Ubuntu server from a VirtualBox or something, but my laptop can't handle that.

I'd like to keep things in the command line, if possible. Thank you for your help!

(Ideal situation: I create a virtual machine with no GUI from command line, while currently in an ssh connection to a home server. Then I ssh into that virtual machine. No GUIs involved whatsoever.)

Comment: “Obviously, this removes things like VirtualBox from the equation, since I'm currently in a command line.” Install Vagrant and VirtualBox on that server and you can do 100% of this via the command line without any GUI involved. How to do that? That’s out of the scope of what can be answered in response to a question on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Giacomo1968, I now have an answer.

1. Install VirtualBox and Vagrant on the server. (via ssh connection)
2. Go to [VagrantCloud](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search) and select your box. For the sake of this example, I'm using [Ubuntu](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64)
3. Create a folder called Ubuntu, and cd into it
4. Initialize the vagrant box [vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64]
5. Activate the virtual machine [vagrant up]
6. After, ssh into it [vagrant ssh]

NOTE: if it asks you for the password for the user vagrant, by default the password is "vagrant" too. (without quotes).

To shut down VM: [vagrant halt]

source: https://www.taniarascia.com/what-are-vagrant-and-virtualbox-and-how-do-i-use-them/